# Which are differentiable for all x?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, graphing-functions, absolute-value

$F_1:$

\begin{cases}
x^2/|x|, & \text{$x \neq 0$} \\
0, & \text{$x=0$}
\end{cases}

$F_2$:$$|\sin(x)|^2$$

$F_3$:$$|\cos(x)|$$

I know that the absolute value of $\cos (x)$ would not be differentiable, but the absolute value of $\sin (x)^2$ would be. Would $F_1$ be differentiable, since the corner is filled in with $(0,0)$?

Comment: Try sketching the functions and you will see cusps where the gradient is not defined

Comment: Should that be $x \neq 0$ in top half of $F_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F_2$ is differentiable for all $x$.

Reason: In order for the function to be differentiable, the derivative must exist and the function must be continuous.

Since $x^2$ is positive for all $x$, we can rewrite $|\sin (x)|^2$ as just plain $\sin(x)^2$.  Then the derivative is $$\dfrac {dy}{dx} = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) = \sin (2x)$$

Then, we determine if the function is continuous (i.e. there are no values that would render the function invalid).  Since $2 \sin (x) \cos (x) = \sin (2x)$ is valid for all values of $x$, it is continuous, so the original function $|\sin(x)|^2$ is also continuous for all $x$.  Hence $F_2$ is differentiable for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your $F_1$, it's $x\neq 0$, otherwise it wouldn't be a function.
$F_1$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

$F_1(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2/|x| & x \neq 0 \\
0  & x=0
\end{cases}$

but $ x^2 =|x|^2$ then $\frac{|x|^2}{|x|}=|x|$

and if $x=0$ then $|x|=0$

Then $F_1$ actually is a strange wording for
$F_1(x)= |x|$

And you know $|x|$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$ because

$\frac{F_1(x+\Delta x)-F_1(x)}{\Delta x}\underset{x\rightarrow 0^+}{\longrightarrow}-1$ but $\frac{F_1(x+\Delta x)-F_1(x)}{\Delta x}\underset{x\rightarrow 0^-}{\longrightarrow}1$
So there's no limit, and that limit is the definition of the derivative and one-variable functions are differentiable at a point if the derivative exists at the same point.

---

For $F_3$ your function isn't differentiable at $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$

To prove that, take two different cases $\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

and notice your function can be written as:

$F_3=|\cos(x)|= \begin{cases}
-\cos(x) & \cos(x) \leq 0 \\
\cos(x)  & \cos(x) > 0
\end{cases} = \begin{cases}
-\cos(x) & x \in \underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}}{\cup} [\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi] \\
\cos(x)  & x \in \underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}}{\cup} (\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi, \frac{5\pi}{2}+2k\pi)
\end{cases} $

Then, at the interior of each interval the derivative is either $-\sin(x)$ or $\sin(x)$

$F'_3(x) = \begin{cases}
\sin(x) & x \in \underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}}{\cup} (\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi) \\
-\sin(x)  & x \in \underset{k\in \mathbb{Z}}{\cup} (\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi, \frac{5\pi}{2}+2k\pi)
\end{cases}$

And that isn't continuous at $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$

---

$F_2$ is differentiable at all x as others have explained.

Comment: Excellent answer for $F_1$ and $F_3!$

Comment: Thanks a lot !

Comment: Would F1 not be differentiable for all x then?

Comment: Suppose $F'_1(0)$ exists
$F'_1(0) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{F_1(x+\Delta x)-F_1(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0^+} \frac{F_1(x+\Delta x)-F_1(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0⁺} \frac{-x-\Delta x+x}{\Delta x}=-1=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0^-} \frac{F_1(x+\Delta x)-F_1(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0^-} \frac{x+\Delta x-x}{\Delta x}=1$
If $F'_1(0)$ exists then -1=1. Then it doesn't exist.

Comment: The interval $(\frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) = \emptyset$.  You should write $(-\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi)$.  Also, if you type `$\sin x$` and `$\cos x$`, you will obtain $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, respectively, which distinguishes the function from its argument and ensures proper spacing.

Comment: Fixed! thank you!